# Google Login Failed, Failed to open stream Http request failed and Bad Request

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, tankauth

**How to change file_get_contents() to curl funtion**

Error occured in this below lines like.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Required option not passed: access_token ' in E:\xampp\htdocs\google\application\libraries\oauth2\Token\Access.php:44 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\google\application\libraries\oauth2\Token.php(30): OAuth2_Token_Access->__construct(NULL) #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\google\application\libraries\oauth2\Provider.php(224): OAuth2_Token::factory('access', NULL) #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\google\application\libraries\oauth2\Provider\Google.php(61): OAuth2_Provider->access('4/tJi51U-xhCSYo...', Array) #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\google\application\controllers\auth_oa2.php(32): OAuth2_Provider_Google->access('4/tJi51U-xhCSYo...') #4 [internal function]: Auth_oa2->session('google') ...

```
    $opts = array(
                'http' => array(
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => http_build_query($params),
                )
            );

            $_default_opts = stream_context_get_params(stream_context_get_default());
            $context = stream_context_create(array_merge_recursive($_default_opts['options'], $opts));
            $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

            $return = json_decode($response, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using curl,

```
$opts = array(
                'http' => array(
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'content' => http_build_query($params),
                )
            );

            $_default_opts = stream_context_get_params(stream_context_get_default());
            $context = stream_context_create(array_merge_recursive($_default_opts['options'], $opts));
```

Instead of above code use this,

```
$_default_opts = stream_context_get_params(stream_context_get_default());
$context = array_merge($_default_opts['options'], $params);

         $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($context));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Now i removed that http_built_query. But it shows again error... Fatal error: Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]])

Comment: can you please post the value in `$context` @JanaSan

Comment: when i print_r($response); it shows like a, { "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Code was already redeemed." }

Comment: `Code was already redeemed` then the server receives two request. So check your port

Comment: in stead of `post`, you may use `get` method, For that just remove `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($context));` these two line from curl and append your parameters to the `$url`